# Java & Casting generic object

Tags: java, casting

Let's imagine :

```
public class Test
{
class A
{
    private String name = "toto";
    public String getId()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
class B
{
    int id = 99;
    public String getId()
    {
        return String.valueOf(id);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Test t = new Test();

    A a = t.new A();
    B b = t.new B();

    List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
    list.add(a);
    list.add(a);
    list.add(a);

    List<?> genericList = list;

    for(Object obj : genericList)
        {
        System.out.println(obj.getId());
    }
}
}
```

System.out.println has error on compile

```
The method getId() is undefined for the type Object
```

Ok, it's normal.

But how can I do for having it working ?
Is it possible to have something like

```
((obj.getClass().getSimpleName())obj).getId()
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you try to achieve, but why don't you use an interface:

```
interface IDHolder{

    String getId();
}

class A implements IDHolder{
    @Override
    String getId(){...}
}


class B implements IDHolder{
    @Override
    String getId(){...}
}

class Runner{
    List<? extends IDHolder> myObjectsWithIds = new ArrayList<>();
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    myObjectsWithIds.add(a);
    myObjectsWithIds.add(b);
    for(IDHolder idHolder : myObjectsWithIds){
        idHolder.getId();
    }
}
```

If you cannot change them, wrap them:

```
class WrappedA implements IDHolder{
    private A a;

    public WrappedA(A a){
        this.a = a;
    } 
    @Override
    String getId(){
         return a.getId();
    }
}

class WrappedB implements IDHolder{
    private B b;

    public WrappedB(B b){
        this.b = b;
    } 
    @Override
    String getId(){
         return b.getId();
    }
}

class Runner{
    List<? extends IDHolder> myObjectsWithIds = new ArrayList<>();
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    WrappedA wA = new WrappedA(a);
    WrappedB wB = new WrappedB(b);
    myObjectsWithIds.add(wA);
    myObjectsWithIds.add(wB);
    for(IDHolder idHolder : myObjectsWithIds){
        idHolder.getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't change A and B classes.

Comment: @tweetysat You don't have to change them - you can create `class A1 extends A implements IDHolder` and `class B1 extends B implements IDHolder` and use these instead of `A` and `B`, respectively. The rest of the answer as suggested by @Balázs will hold as is. The only sane alternative for you would be to use reflection for invoking `getID` at runtime.

Comment: For the List<? ....  I got "'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7"

Comment: Try `List<? extends IDHolder> myObjectsWithIds = new ArrayList<IDHolder>();`

Answer (score 1):

As you can't change your classes, you have 2 solutions :

1) If you exactly know which classes you are working with, use instanceof (even if instanceof is itself a proof of a design flaw...)

```
for(Object obj : genericList){
    if(obj instanceof A){
      System.out.println(((A)obj).getId());
    }
    if(obj instanceof B){
      System.out.println(((B)obj).getId());
    }
}
```

2) If you do not know your classes at all, but know that they must have a getId() method, use introspection / reflection to get this getter

Comment: +1 for avoiding reflection (which is not always bad) in this particular case! Loved your smart and easy solution!

Answer (score 0):

No, castings are done using fixed (at compile time) classes. In fact that is the idea of it, so the compiler knows (by way of programmer intervention) which class he is dealing it (and can ensure that no unexistent methods are invoked).

You can use reflection to dynamically invoke a method from a given object, but it is a little more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0):

A nice approach would be to create an interface called

```
public interface IdProvider {

  String getId();

}
```

make `A` and `B` implement them

```
class A implements IdProvider
{
    private String name = "toto";
    public String getId()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
class B implements IdProvider
{
    int id = 99;
    public String getId()
    {
        return String.valueOf(id);
    }
}
```

and have a generic `List<IdProvider>`

```
List<IdProvider> list = new ArrayList<IdProvider>();
list.add(a);
list.add(a);
list.add(a);
list.add(b);
list.add(b);

for(IdProvider obj : genericList)
{
    System.out.println(obj.getId());
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Same than above.  I can't change the classes.

Comment: Would it be possible to change the type of 'obj'  like obj = (A) obj

Comment: my task is to remove that interface. how do you think I should deal with that?